# Is AS 3 capable of supporting a game with 600 + rotating images?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I made a simple game where squares collect crystals and bring them to a base and replicate.  They are just .png images that rotate and move and yet when their number becomes greater than 500, the game starts to lag out.  In Java I'm able to do a similar thing with 30,000 units.  Could I be doing something wrong or is Flash just not that capable?

I'm using Flash Builder.
I get the image like this:

```
[Embed(source="../lib/red.png")]
public var redImgClass:Class;
public var redImg = new redImgClass();
```

Then I pass redImg to a "unit" class which takes an instance of "Bitmap"
I change its "rotation" and x,y members every frame.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not using Stage3D. If you use Starling, ND2D or write your own Stage3D wrapper you'll be able to get better performance.

You can also take a look at Jackson Dunstan's blog, this post is especially helpful: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2279

Comment: Wow, thank you Daniel I am floored.  This is incredibly helpful.  I will definitely use Stage3d from now on.

Comment: ND2D has been discontinued, so note that too. Also Adobe supports Starling.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is correct in that you should use the Stage3D APIs for greater performance. He didn't however mention that you should seriously consider using [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/), which wraps the Stage3D API with much easier to use classes:

- [Learn more about Starling here](http://gamua.com/starling/).
- [Example of the level of performance you could expect from Stage3D](http://files.jacksondunstan.com/articles/2279/BitmapScaleRotFlash2.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer is to use blitting, that is, use a single `Bitmap` object to draw everything on via `copyPixels()`. This requires that your rotating crystal PNG be replicated into a sequence of rotated images, which you then use instead of directly changing `rotation` property. This approach is more performance-friendly, and does not depend on video card performance like Stage3D does.

- [Adobe's manual on blitting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/actionscript_blitting.html)
- [Some discussion on blitting done by game devs](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4-game-programming/topics/343854-lifes-a-blitch)

Answer (score 0):

Starling is what you`re looking for (http://gamua.com/starling/)